# Flask variable for app_context

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Each time you use the self-written CLI command, a call to app_context occurs, as a result of which extra Blueprint is connected, as well as loggers that are called when the project starts.
Is there any list or variable in which I can write from WHERE the call to `app_context` occurs.
`__name__` is the same everywhere, always returns 'app'.

`project.py`:

```
from app import create_app, cli
app = create_app()
cli.register(app)
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Project startup')

    return app
```

`app.logger.info('Project startup')` called every time when I'm calling CLI command.
What condition can be added for not call this function when using CLI commands?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `log level` if you want to disable `app.logger` logs. Let's check:

```
app = Flask('')
# app logs are disabled. uncomment to see app logs.
# app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.info('Project startup')
```

So you can configure `log level` using additional argument:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config, log_level=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    if log_level:
        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

One more good way is use 2 different configs(first - for `web app`, second - for `CLI app`). In this case you'll have possibility to customize any setting(including  `log level`).